# How in C++ use templates to call specific members of supplied type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming

Lets assume we have two classes

```
struct A
{
    int x = 1;
};

struct B
{
    int y = 2;
};
```

I want to have template that will return value of member (in a case of A I want to return value of "x", in case of B I want to return value of "y").

Example call:

```
const auto myVariable = f<A>();
```

or

```
A a;
const auto myVariable = f<A>(a);
```

I don't want to have 2 template specializations - ideally it would be one template with some kind of "if statement", but maybe it is not possible?

It may be written with C++11 (but not with C++14).

Generally how you are using templates when you have such problems - quite big template and only in one or two places you need to take values from different members - which may be deduced based of type of that variable.

PROBLEM: unnecessary it is not allowed to modify classes A and B

Comment: As far as I know without specialisation you can't but you can make a getter with the same name in both classes

Comment: Unnecessary I cannot modify class A and B (sorry for missing this important information)

Comment: Having two specializations _is_ like having an if statement (well, I suppose it's more like having a `switch` statement with two cases, but same thing). If your concern is that your template has other stuff and you don't want to repeat it, you could make a helper template whose sole purpose in life is to manage this choice.

Comment: @Hurkyl I think your answer is the best - please write this answer so I could mark this as solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case you ask for the template because you want to switch between A and B at compile time...and you have a reason not to simply typedef A or B directly...

```
struct A
{
    int x;
};
struct B
{
    int y;
};
struct A1 : public A { int Get() const { return x; } };
struct B1 : public B { int Get() const { return y; } };

// Begin possible shortcut avoiding the template below:
#ifdef USE_A
typedef A1 Bar;
#endif
#ifdef USE_B
typedef B1 Bar;
#endif
// End possible shortcut.

template <class _Base>
struct CompileTimeAOrB
    : public _Base
{
    int Get() const
    {
        return _Base::Get();
    }
};

#define USE_A
//#define USE_B

#ifdef USE_A
typedef CompileTimeAOrB<A1> Foo;
#endif
#ifdef USE_B
typedef CompileTimeAOrB<B1> Foo;
#endif
```

**EDIT**: Since A and B cannot be changed, introduced A1, B1 ;)

Comment: Unnecessary I cannot modify class A and B (sorry for missing this important information)

Answer (score 6):

Why use templates at all?

```
int f(const A& a) { return a.x; }
int f(const B& b) { return b.y; }
```

Comment: Let's imagine I have quite big template and inside it I need to do some common work on all of them, but I need in addition take few different parameters based on type (same amount, different fields). It could be for me easier to just take object or type and inside template hide all informations needed for computations. So helper functions like this are not best idea (In real scenario I will have too create 3 for each type)

Comment: @Adrian I have difficulty understanding what you mean. I would suggest asking a new question with a better example, because my answer perfectly solves the example given.

Comment: But I provided example call and I added that I need template. In a f(a) I was thinking still about template, just did not added type as it is not necessary, I will correct this.

Comment: @Adrian I don't want to be rude, but I simply do not understand your English, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    int value;
    A() : value(2) {}
};

struct B
{
    int value;
    B() : value(4) {}
};

template <typename T>
int GetValue(T t)
{
    return t.value;
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;
    std::cout << GetValue(a) << std::endl;
    std::cout << GetValue(b) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In order for it to work, you'd need to have the same variable or function named declared in each class you wanted this to work with.

Comment: Unnecessary I cannot modify class A and B (sorry for missing this important information)